# Groovy XmlSlurper get value out of NodeChildren

Tags: groovy, html-parsing, xmlslurper, nodechildren

I'm parsing HTML and trying to get full / not parsed value out of one particular node.

HTML example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Hello <br> World <br> !</div>
        <div><object width="420" height="315"></object></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
def tagsoupParser = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(tagsoupParser)
def htmlParsed = slurper.parseText(stringToParse)

println htmlParsed.body.div[0]
```

However it returns only text in case of first node and I get empty string for the second node. Question: how can I retrieve value of the first node such that I get:

```
Hello <br> World <br> !
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I used to get the content from the first `div` tag (omitting xml declaration and namespaces).

#### Groovy

```
@Grab('org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1')
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser
import groovy.xml.*

def html = """<html>
    <body>
        <div>Hello <br> World <br> !</div>
        <div><object width="420" height="315"></object></div>
    </body>
</html>"""

def parser = new Parser()
parser.setFeature('http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces',false)
def root = new XmlSlurper(parser).parseText(html)
println new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bindNode(root.body.div[0]).toString()
```

#### Gives

```
<div>Hello <br clear='none'></br> World <br clear='none'></br> !</div>
```

**N.B.** Unless I'm mistaken, Tagsoup [is adding the closing tags](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/#what). If you literally want `Hello <br> World <br> !`, you might have to use a different library (maybe regex?).

I know it's including the `div` element in the output... is this a problem?

Comment: Yeah, I would like not to include the 'div'. If you can find a way, that would be great!!!

Comment: All I've got at the moment is ...`.toString().replaceAll(/^<div>|<\/div>$/, "")`. Not sure if there's a way using the StreamingMarkupBuilder.